# Is cultural appropriation bad?

Tags: cultural-appropriation

Cultural appropriation, as a commonly touched-upon concept, could be defined as “taking” something from a “culture” that you are “not a part of”.

Naturally, each of the above words and phrases in quotes deserves analysis as to what each of them means, in more detail. We would need to ask how meaningful or decidable it really is to assert who is from what culture, and what culture is not their culture. Since we all are born a blank slate, we all have to learn a culture from the outside. Is there a cut-off in age, where after that age, exposure to “culture” no longer counts as you developing within that culture as an internal member? Of course, it sounds arbitrary and that the principle may be difficult to justify without ambiguity.

The only perspective I have been exposed to so far that sounds like it has an interesting perspective to inform the matter on, is theories of colonialism. Colonial theory may make it clearer why some people find it ethical to oppose when a minority group has its culture appropriate by a dominant group, but not vice versa.

I think it’s interesting to note that the word “appropriate” did not (I believe), have a negative connotation until maybe some time around 2013, if I recall correctly. “Appropriate” comes from *a propos*, which means “*to the self*” in Latin. Thus, to appropriate used to be more synonymous with the word “to adopt”, or “to adapt”: to take something outside of your ordinary sphere of intimate or personal possession, and to bring it into that domain: thus, to make something your own. For example, I believe that Islam appropriated the pre-existing religions of Christianity and Judaism in its theology, which it was exposed to in its environment. In this case, appropriate could simply mean, “to make use of”. “Appropriate” may sometimes be used in a negative way, to mean “forcible seizure”: “We have appropriated your possessions and impounded your vehicle” is perhaps something a government worker could say. I think that appropriation can indicate creativity or originality: when you take something out of its original context, and *re-purpose* it.

I also sometimes worry that critics of cultural appropriation are not morally self-consistent, because they may criticize the way a person interacts with some artifact of a foreign culture, possibly on the implied moral basis that that person is disrespecting that culture, diminishing it, or that they have unequal power over those people. Yet, this attempt at protecting a certain exploited social group might fail to take into account what members of that social group themselves actually want. If they support whatever the cultural appropriation is, we might have the contradiction that someone is dominantly asserting what those people are supposed to think or want, on their behalf, under the guise that they are acting morally in their interests. One article that interested me circa 2014 was a survey that found that a majority of Native Americans supported the use of Native American iconography or figures for sports mascots, counter to a prevailing notion that it is offensive to display a person’s identity as a mascot. In that article, a professor interviewed commented that the result was disappointing, because they *should* oppose it. Maybe the professor is right, but it opens the weird moral conundrum where, as I said above, in believing you are acting in someone’s benefit based on a stark moral conviction, you might actually become so influenced by a belief that you do not care what those people want themselves; which could be immoral in its own way. (It also potentially exhibits irony, where, yet again, a dominant culture’s beliefs are ruling over the minority culture’s ones). Sometimes we might try to make moral arguments by symmetry: I myself wouldn’t be offended by a sports team using a caricature of a Viking as a mascot, which touches to some extent on my “personal identity”. But of course, we don’t always know if the situations genuinely are symmetrical.

One commonly hears in newspapers that a certain country or cultural group requests the return of certain artifacts which are known to have been taken in the past, by another cultural group. I have sometimes wondered if this happens much more for white, Western countries; in other words, that abject opposition to cultural theft has deeper underlying factors explaining why it is a matter of concern to people: because Western countries are associated with domination, thus, their continued possession of those artifacts is more interpretable in the context of unfair treatment. But again, if we explore the topic with rigor, there may be issues due to the concepts not being precisely defined enough. For example, once, I read that a Native American tribe requested the return of certain artifacts. However, they were able to test DNA related to the artifacts, and they found that that tribe was not related to the tribe whose artifacts they were. It opens the question how often we have someone today claiming something is theirs, based on the belief that the artifact belonged to their cultural group, in the past. But the ethics of possession are more varied than simply everyone from a cultural group sharing possession of all things. What if, unbeknownst to us, the artifact was voluntarily given, in the past, then inherited down generations? It would not seem that a modern person from a certain country has the right to claim ownership of that object.

A lot of these ideas are based on heavy reification of the idea of social groups. This is philosophically challenging, because although one can claim their existence is more flexible and arbitrary than is sometimes suggested, it also often seems untenable to completely deny the reality of cultural groups, on the other hand. (I don’t know if you could call this “sociological atheism” or something, the absolute rejection of all non-objective categories). Still, it is easy to see how arbitrary some of these claims are. Nowadays, we may talk about Native Americans as a single social entity, sometimes; yet, one can consider that in the past, they thought of themselves as different, even opposing, groups of people. Similarly, what is now called “white people” may not have been a contiguous cultural group some time in the past. This opens questions about if collective responsibility and collective reparations are logically coherent: why would a person living today be morally associated with a person in the past, just because they have similar skin color? For example. In other contexts, the very same people who make such claims may object to this principle as an immoral stereotypification of a people.

Is cultural appropriation bad?

Comment: [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-cultural-heritage/) may help. i suppose the term cultural appropriation contains the judgment that it is wrong or illegitimate, while not all potential cases count, so you might be asking does it ever really occur

Comment: One difference between the Vikings and the Indians is that the Vikings was intended to pay homage to the Scandinavian heritage *ascendant* in Minnesota, and "Indians" refers to a *conquered* people of it's region. And in fact, such mascots have been shown to increase anti-native bias and decrease self-esteem in Native teens.

Comment: Imo this is the wrong question - one should ask "is it metaphysically possible to appropriate part of a culture; if so is anything called cultural appropriation actually an instance of that possible thing; if not is any of it still wrong, and what category of wrong things describes it?"

Comment: Similarly to how "is intellectual property theft wrong" should really be "is unlicensed copying theft? If not, what is it, and is the thing that it is wrong?"

Comment: I guess you didn't have time to make this shorter, but it does bring up a lot of interesting points. I remember reading an interview with a man from Africa who said, "*There are no black people in Africa.*" And that's the news from Lake Wobegon

Comment: [from Latin ad "to" + propriare "take as one's own," from proprius "one's own"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/appropriate)

Comment: Voting to close my own question as it’s opinion-based.

Comment: @gs I like that, I’ll try to work that into the question. Also here’s another relevant source for myself: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/black-reparations/

Answer (score 2):

For the primary issue of the moral valence of cultural appropriation, I would suggest that the ethics can be understood by **analogy to the idea of copyright**. The purpose of copyright law is to ensure that the person who creates intellectual property benefits from it. The practical assumption is that, without copyright, there's no incentive for people to do creative work, and the moral belief is that taking the work without compensation is a form of theft. In the case of a cultural heritage, the products of the culture can be seen as pseudo property, held in common by the heirs of the culture. Using it without attribution or compensation is therefore arguably also a form of theft, no different from the theft of communal land.

There are other significant questions at work here:

- Can cultural property ever be legitimately alienated (given away or sold)?
- Who gets to decide?
- What counts as cultural property?
- Who counts as a member of the culture?
- What is the proper redress or compensation for cultural appropriation?
- Is there a "statute of limitations" for appropriation?

I would argue that we can have legitimate disagreements over the specifics of the secondary questions, while still agreeing on the primary ethical principle.

Comment: This is an interesting thought, but I'm not sure Copyright is a good analogy. Copyright has for as long as it existed been available only for a limited time. In the U.S. the Constitution mandates that it must exist only for a limited time. And in many versions the limited time was fairly short. 

Notably, the limitation on copyright is very different from a statute of limitations. A statute of limitations says we will no longer redress certain wrongs after a time period for practical reasons. An expiration on copyright says it is no longer unlawful at all to use works once it has expired.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you seem to have gotten the etymology of "appropriate" wrong. Appropriate apparently does not refer to "a propos", which you might be able to translate as "to the self", but is probably more aptly described as ["to the purpose (of)"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/apropos), so "apropos X" is just a fancy way for the introductory phrase of "And about the topic of X ...". While appropriation would rather be translated as "[to add to one's property](https://www.etymonline.com/word/appropriate)".

Now sure people might scream "etymological fallacy" and how words change their meaning over time and how "appropriate" is probably more often associated with "(culturally) acceptable" such as if you judge the response to something,  if it's "appropriate" than the other person could have known it before hand, it's what you're supposed to do in that situation, maybe you could also describe it as proportional. But a) you could probably go on a limb and argue that this still somewhat follows the pattern and that a custom is just already "made one's own" so much so in fact that it is now one's own and as such the acceptable measured response within that culture. So the word still expresses the idea of it being taken, but the culture has lost the feeling of it being a foreign custom and truly made it their own.
And b) "cultural appropriation" seems to be a term that specifically emerged in the [context of the post colonial debate so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_appropriation#Academic_study) so to an extend you can expect that the terminology is not just coincidental but that the etymology of taking someone else's culture and making it your own is chosen pretty deliberately.

And whether that is good or bad depends on how you define "cultural appropriation", because there are a lot of angles from which you could look at that and judge it.

First of all you could ask if you can appropriate and own culture in the first place. Or what "[culture](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/culture/#DefiCult)" even is. Culture is broadly speaking the norms and customs within a group. So does culture refer to the group? Does it refer to the values, traditions, mutual experiences of the members? Is it how they interact with each other? Can it exist in a void, so can there be a culture without people living it? Or people living without developing a culture? Is it static or dynamic? Is it inclusive or exclusive and how would that be facilitated/prevented?

And apparently the answer is "yes", all of these and probably many more (despite their obvious contradiction with each other) are at times used under term "culture". And within some of these definitions the concept of property makes not the least bit of sense while for others it might be essential.

So there's unfortunately plenty of opportunities to side track any discussion on cultural appropriation by simply referring to a definition of culture where the whole argument doesn't work.

That being said from what I've heard about it, the discussion around "cultural appropriation" seems to be more about colonial crimes and their legacy in post-colonial societies, as well as the [epistemic injustice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_injustice) (as well as monetary hardship resulting from that) of minorities (within a majority culture) when it comes to the broader collective (majority + minority).

So idk the practical utility of ancient artifacts for modern civilizations is probably pretty low, either way they are most likely not going to be used with their intended purpose but instead are likely to be studied by historians, displayed in a museum or bought/stolen by a collector. However despite their apparent uselessness, they might nonetheless be tremendously important for the cultural narrative of a country (or at the very least their bank account when they get to sell it to a collector or collect ticket prices of museums, instead of the thieves also pocketing that money).

So for example often enough the colonizing powers proclaimed the narrative that the native population is primitive that their culture is worthless or that they don't have any in the first place and that the colonizers are doing them a favor by supplying them with their own culture and that they are stupid for not picking up immediately what they have taken decades to internalize, but yet consider "their nature". So in effect a lot of the knowledge, history and customs of that place is lost to time or passed on with distortions (oral history), as persistent artifacts (artificial = "not naturally made") might have been stolen or destroyed. So the ability to evolve one's culture and understanding of the world by interacting with one's environment might have been massively curtailed, while on the other hand the colonizing culture was likely also a one-way-street so the ability to contribute to that culture by "cultural appropriation" and making it your own and developing it by yourself was also curtailed (not a mix or contribution but and "error" and "doing it wrong"). Maybe in some domains that might have let to as stronger development of immaterial culture so art, sports, physical skills, knowledge, stories etc, because what is not physical cannot be physically taken or destroyed.

So the value of cultural artifacts might go way beyond their monetary or use value, but they might also serve as evidence of history, as proof for a cultural narrative, as a development of culture over time. While their absence at first leaves a lack and might change the arc of development, but also gives the thieve power over it's victim, due to the ability to "define their culture". For example to deny someone a history and culture due to a lack of evidence or making use them to do the interpreting of them, telling another culture that they are primitive and what they believe is wrong based on selective and biased interpretation of stolen artifacts.

So in a sense the culture of a group might be the property of someone else, who can change and distort the story as they please while you only have the chance to give up your history and live in the moment or the future or to live in and with this distorted version of your own history.

1984 might come to mind where Orwell argues that if you construct the policy of the future by taking inspiration of the past (whether that's following a culture, or simply being able to use data and trends), then controlling someone's past is controlling their future. And that process of eradicating history and replacing it by the version of the oppressors is in fact one of the major sources of power in that book. Another example this, this time not of the colonized but the colonizers might be neonazis and white supremacists who constantly try to deny the holocaust or downplay their crimes and the influence of their crimes, because in a world where that memory of the crimes persist they have a much harder time to promote their narrative of historical necessity based on a history where they've always been the good guys and you know "never touch a running system"...

So it's an interesting discussion whom the ability should fall to, to determine their own history and to tell the story about a person/group. The person itself, an observer, science (also an observer but with a stronger nimbus of neutrality, though likely also not perfectly unbiased)? How do you assure factfulness? Taking into account perspectives including the subjective ones? How do you avoid biases? Detect lies and not just inaccuracies and misinterpretations?

Which brings us to the other problem about culture and minorities in larger societies.

Which is the "mainstream". Which is technically just the set of values, customs and tastes that the majority of people can agree upon (at a given point in time). So it's not a specific group and not a specific ideology, in fact it can incorporate quite a lot of contradicting elements. But nonetheless due to being a representation of a majority it is usually taken serious and indirectly or directly shapes the social and political discussions, majorities might have an easier time to be represented, despite the fact that everyone swims in it whether they want to or not. Also there are quite a lot of actors who would like to make whatever they want or perceive the current mainstream to be, to be a normative set of rules for everyone.

The latter usually creates lots of problems for minorities as their concerns might be underrepresented leading to the biggest adaption workload being placed upon them even to the point where they can only fail even if they would have actually wanted to adopt. (whether adoption of the mainstream is a good thing is an entirely different but worthwhile question).

But even if it's not normative but just what everyone else seems to be doing, that can lead to problems of people who cannot or don't want to "fit in". Which leads to vibrant sub cultures where people express themselves outside of the written and unwritten rules of the mainstream, which are usually more inclusive and less restrictive and produce their own kind of cultural norms and values (can't really get around that, even "there are no rules" is a rule). And because people often get bored with the mainstream if it always stays the same and doesn't evolve. Which it often has a problem with, as evolution means trying out new stuff which is likely to propel you outside of the comfort zone of the mainstream. It happens that the evolution of the mainstream happens through cultural appropriation of subcultures. Meaning those minorities put in the heavy duty work of creating something interesting and unique, but the mainstream only really pays attention to it once they've shown a prove of concept of being able to be viable.

And at that point either a mainstream viable artist will hear of it and dip their toes into that culture propelling it into the mainstream while taking the lion share of the credit for doing so (either because no one pays attention to what they say is their inspiration or because they don't give credit to begin with). An especially controversial topic is when people take credit for folksongs of other countries copyrighting and thus literally culturally appropriating stuff that was in the public domain of that group and in the worst case even making them pay for that (copyright strikes, disallowing of public performances without pay etc).

Another version is when the mainstream audience discovers an artist of that subculture and propels them into the mainstream, where they either get showered with money and taught by success and failure what kind of art they need to produce to make even more, upon which they will likely be abandoned by their own subculture and branded as sellouts. Or where the mainstream art machine realizes there's a new market and just produces copycat versions of that to the point where the original subculture is completely forgotten and Frankenstein versions of that culture are now dominating the mainstream but the subculture is back to square one in terms of being disenfranchised by the mainstream that now celebrates them but also gives them the middle finger with regards to everything they wanted to achieve with that.

Though either way the cultural hegemony usually remains with the majority culture and they retain the definitional authority even when it refers to something that was created, developed, mastered and had relevancy to a minority.

The other thing is that cultural appropriation is usually shallow with regards to the original. So when in the original culture it had a symbolism, a ritualistic purpose, was meant as a fable or taught some philosophy or whatnot in mainstream culture it might suffice if it looks cool.

On the other hand in order for it to not be blunt and shallow, you'd likely also have to allow for cultural appropriation in the sense of "making it your own". That is not just learning and appreciating a culture (as something foreign), but making it your own culture, taking part in it, playing around with it and evolving it by your own contributions. So by gatekeeping a culture as a static group or ideology one is also kinda ensuring that it stays "elite" (=small in size literally something like "selected (few)") and as such that it will likely stagnate and eventually fade into obscurity. Not to mention that by making it exclusive one also requests some sort of exclusionary property over something that is already happening in the "public domain" (not in the legal sense, but in the sense that it's something that people see and interact with in public and which will, almost inevitably, be part of their life and culture one way or another because you react to your environment).

So there are a lot of angles to that and I probably still missed a whole lot and I doubt you can give an easy verdict on whether that is good or bad, it's rather that there are already certain aspects of that which are problematic and that there need to be discussions on how to resolve those and find non-exploitative alternatives.

Also another point, this cultural appropriation, even though it might feel like that from the point of those being stolen from, might not even come from a place of malice, yet it might still result in a situation where something is taken away, stripped of it's meaning, where people are left even without a reference to their own art and usually also including not being paid for that.

Also while I describe that mostly in terms of mainstream and minority, because I think this pattern is not exclusive to racism and colonialism, the discussion is usually often heavily rooted there because in those domains it's explicitly prevalent and likely a lot more effectively harmful.

Comment: [from Latin ad "to" + propriare "take as one's own," from proprius "one's own"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/appropriate)